# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands 'method group' or 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following code:

```
  <span>@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Select(x => x.Name == "Fish")</span>
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands 'method group' or 'string'

I don't understand why I get this.

Here you can see a picture of ContactDetails:
'[image]

I want to access the ContactDataType property and compare the Name-property that Is Inside ContactDataType, but I don't know how do It. So basically, I want this: `@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.ContactDataType.Select(x => x.Name == "PrimaryPhone")`

Comment: As for accessing the `Name` property of the `ContractDataType` property, use simply the typical C# nested object property dot notation, e.g. `x.ContractDataType.Name`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: No, this don't work..

Comment: I didn't say it will solve the whole issue - as others mentioned in the answers, you should use `Where` instead of `Select`. The above is just how you can access the property you need inside the `Where`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I don't know how to access the property ContactDataType...

Comment: `@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Where(x => x.ContactDataType.Name == "Fish")`

Answer (score 7):

You need to apply it to your `Where` not `Select` function:

```
<span>@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Where(x => x.Name == "Fish").FirstOrDefault()</span>
```

Or even better:

```
<span>@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Fish")</span>
```

Comment: It can ebe `@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Fish")`

Comment: True buddy. Thanks!

Comment: @Oluwafemi: No, this don't work. I get the same error.

Comment: Then you will have to give us more information like the model class structure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you try to access the `Name` member which is probably a method and not a property.
On your screenshot we can see all available properties: `ContactDataType`, `DebuggerDisplay`, `Detail`, `Id` and `PersonId`. There is no `Name`. If it is a property you must add `()` to `Name` to execute it:

```
@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Select(x => x.Name() == "Fish")
```

This will return a `IEnumerable<Boolean>` but probably you want something else.
Maybe this?

```
@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name() == "Fish")
      .ContactDataType
```

This will return the first `ContactDetail`s `ContactDataType` which `Name()` equals `"Fish"`.

Comment: @Bryan That's strange. Can you show us the `Name`-member? Is it a method? What does it return? I assumed it returns a string, than it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Select Api is reserved for selection of properties, in your case, you want to filter by the value of a property, so use Where :
`<span>@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Where(x => x.Name == "Fish").FirstOrDefault().Select(x => x.Name)</span>`